# How to pick items from warehouse to minimise travel in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, combinations, combinatorics, picking

I am looking at this problem from a TSQL point of view, however any advice would be appreciated.

**Scenario**

I have 2 sets of criteria which identify items in a warehouse to be selected.

Query 1 returns 100 items
Query 2 returns 100 items

I need to pick any 25 of the 100 items returned in query 1.
I need to pick any 25 of the 100 items returned in query 2.
- The items in query 1/2 will not be the same, ever.

Each item is stored in a segment of the warehouse. 

A segment of the warehouse may contain numerous items.

I wish to select the 50 items (25 from each query) in a way as to reduce the number of segments I must visit to select the items.

**Suggested Approach**

My initial idea has been to combined the 2 result sets and produce a list of

Segment ID, NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegment

I would then select 25 items from each query, giving preference to those in a segments with the most NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegment. 
I know this would not be optimal but would be an easy to implement heuristic.

**Questions**

1) I suspect this is a standard combinational problem, but I don't recognise it.. perhaps multiple knapsack, does anyone recognise it?

2) Is there a better (easy-ish to impliment) heuristic or solution - ideally in TSQL?

Many thanks.

Comment: Solved this yet? I'm not sure I follow, but can't you just do a SELECT TOP 50 * FROM ((SELECT * FROM q1) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM q2)) c ORDER BY NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegment DESC

Comment: Hi Fredrik, nope because I still need exactly 25 from each list

Comment: Then perhaps SELECT * FROM ((SELECT TOP 25 * FROM q1 ORDER BY NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegment) UNION ALL (SELECT TOP 25 * FROM q2 ORDER BY NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegment)) a . Or, it would be great if you could expand/rephrase the question.

Comment: I work mainly in IT support for warehousing.  I do consulting and have seen dozens of warehouses without ever encountering a problem remotely like this.  May I ask why you need to do this?  Perhaps there is a better functional solution. 

From a technical perspective is "segmentID" a property of items?

Comment: TizzyFoe - To answer your question, this warehouse holds items at between -80 and -196 celcius, and every time you 'visit' a segment, you pose a risk to it because the temperature spikes when you access it therefore the less segments visited the better. Yes, segmentID can be seen as a property of items (it uses a join to get it, but yep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might also not be optimal but i think would at least perform fairly well.

Calculate this set for query 1.

```
Segment ID, NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegment
```

take the top 25, Just by sorting by NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegment. call this subset A.

take the top 25 from query 2, by joining to A and sorting by "case when A.segmentID is not null  then 1 else 0, NumberOfItemsRequiredInSegmentFromQuery2".

repeat this but take the top 25 from query 2 first.  return the better performing of the 2 sets.

The one scenario where i think this fails would be if you got something like this.

```
Segment   Count Query 1    Count Query 2
A         10               1
B         5                1
C         5                1
D         5                4
E         5                4
F         4                4
G         4                5
H         1                5
J         1                5
K         1                10
```

You need to make sure you choose A, D, E, from when choosing the best segments from query 1.  To deal with this you'd almost still need to join to query two,  so you can get the count from there to use as a tie breaker.

Comment: I'm waist deep in something else, but thanks very much for the answer, I hope to get my head round it in the next day or so! Again, genuinly, thanks so much for your answer.